# How to split a string based on specific character position

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following string as an input, and I need to break (parse) it into pieces based on specific known positions, i.e.:

`string = 374450012349999106006104034174003704175003704`

`position 0,2 - 37
position 3,5 - 445
position 6,10 - 123
etc.`

how do I do this using javascript, and then display the results in html?
sorry if silly

Thanks!

Comment: Use [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). You can try something by yourself before ask a question.

Comment: Please try to elaborate your questions, check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please try to elaborate your questions and add code so we can help you this link will point you in the right direction http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 0):

The method `.substring(start, stop)` is generally used for this type of activity. 
Where *start* is the index in the string which you wish to begin the substring and *stop* indicates the index position you wish to end on **but not include**.

For example,

To display in HTML one could simply:

```
<h1 id="myDisplay></h1>
```

JavaScript

```
var display = document.getElementById("myDisplay");
var myString = "374450012349999106006104034174003704175003704";
var pos1 = myString.substring(0,2);
// Repeat for Pos2 and 3;

display.innerHTML = pos 1;
```